# Unable to execute Ms access db query using UCanAccess

Tags: ucanaccess

1. I am using UCanAccess driver to access MS access db. But while
   executing MS access Query def, the below exception is thrown.

   ```
   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 user
   lacks privilege or object not found: QRYTEMP_STATE_TABLE at
   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareCall(UcanaccessConnection.java:483) at
   ashland.dao.AshlandDAO.getNumberOfStatesCount(AshlandDAO.java:46)
       at ashland.main.Start.main(Start.java:88)  Caused by:
   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not
   found: QRYTEMP_STATE_TABLE at
   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) at
   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) at
   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) at
   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) at
   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source) at
   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareCall(UcanaccessConnection.java:481)
       ... 2 more
   ```

Comment: [Please include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of code that can reproduce this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use either the `console.bat` (Windows) or `console.sh` (Linux, et. al.) UCanAccess utilities to open the database in question. Do you see any errors related to "QRYTEMP_STATE_TABLE" ?

Comment: Using JDBC-ODBC driver I am able to execute the same query Def in java.

Comment: That's good to know, but the `console.bat` output might shed some light on why you are getting an error from UCanAccess.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Using console.bat, I have opened database and I noticed that the qryTemp_State_Table is listed under Loaded Queries:

Comment: I am facing another issue as well. One queryDef1 is using another QueryDef2 for select columns, but QueryDef2 is parameterized query. Since the QueryDef2 is parameterized while executing the queryDef1 it is throwing below expection.                                                                                                             Error message was :user lacks privilege or object not found: PARAMETERS